# Mapbox GL JS, Add custom markers

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I am looking for an approach that would allow me to create a simple custom marker to my map like `Mapbox JS` does.

Had a deep look around the web and it seems there is no obvious or quite straight forward way to achive this. This is quite a functionality that being missed out I guess.

Had a few tries to work with `Mapbox Studio`, but still no luck as it is quite hard to understand how can I upload custom SVG's and the being able to reference them.

So to give an example I have created a custom map with `Mapbox Studio` and as far as I can see there are no icons that I can use. Did try to look for a  something called a sprite sheet, but since I never worked with that kind of approach, I have no idea how to do it.

It is very important I guess not just for me, but for a lot of people who just started learning something new like `Mapbox GL JS` to have a nice guide attached.

So this some of my code in regards to create some custom markers

```js
markers = {

  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-symbol": "golf",
      "type": "journey-step",
      "previous": "0",
      "current": "1",
      "next": "2"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-155.98114013671872,
        19.70207180765683
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7f201e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "music",
      "type": "journey-step",
      "previous": "1",
      "current": "2",
      "next": "3"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-155.67352294921875,
        19.01278705937288
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {

      "icon-symbol": "Four",
      "type": "journey-step",
      "previous": "2",
      "current": "3",
      "next": "4"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-155.2423095703125,
        19.42644883261674
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7f201e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "theatre",
      "type": "journey-step",
      "previous": "3",
      "current": "4",
      "next": "5"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-155.10223388671875,
        19.698193071745962
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7f201e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "alcohol-shop-12",
      "type": "journey-step",
      "previous": "4",
      "current": "5",
      "next": "6"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-155.38787841796872,
        20.04303061200023
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7f201e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "theatre",
      "type": "journey-step",
      "previous": "5",
      "current": "6",
      "next": "7"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-155.8575439453125,
        20.229986070955245
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7f201e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "theatre",
      "type": "journey-step",
      "previous": "6",
      "current": "7",
      "next": "8"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-155.89599609375,
        19.46400263520258
      ]
    }
  }]

};
map.addSource("markers", {
  "type": "geojson",
  "data": markers
});

map.addLayer({
  "id": markers,
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": "markers"
});
```

As you can guess, my map does not display any icons.

Can anyone suggest a good and understandable way of achieving something that vital for a Map library?

Comment: How do you init your map?

Comment: I did find an answer actually myself, will post an answer soon. Will make a small guide in the answer for noobies like me.

Answer (score 3):

Well...

The solution was easier than I thought, thanks to @tristen for posting helpful links and I really hope people find them useful.

I found that the easiest way of doing it, is by following these simple steps.

1) Create a custom map using `Mapbox Studio`

2) Upload your custom markers/icons to images (just edit your map click properties (bottom left corner) -> click on any layer -> icon -> add SVG images, (if you've made custom icons yourself, like i did using Adobe Illustrator, make sure save them in an old format (legacy something...), or your icons will be black and white) -> and hit save)

3) Reference the map you've created in your `JavaScript` file like this

```
map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map', // container id
      style: 'mapbox://styles/username/aasdasdassdfsdfsdfsdf131', //stylesheet location
      center: [ -115.15628814697266,
          36.173079792635654], // starting position
      zoom: 10.5
        // starting zoom
    });
```

4) Now you can reference your markers/icons, for example I've uploaded and SVG called `golf.svg` so when I define my layer I can do this:  `"marker-symbol": "golf"`

And thats pretty much it.

Answer (score 2):

Some links:

1. There's documentation here on creating custom markers in Studio and adding them to a Mapbox GL JS map: https://www.mapbox.com/help/custom-markers/
2. While I wouldn't endorse doing it this way, here's an example that plots a point on a map using a custom DOM element: http://bl.ocks.org/tristen/10b69f89b600ca0433fdc472db6a6cab
3. This comment (and discussion!) provides backstory on why a use case like displaying a custom marker requires a couple extra steps: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/656#issuecomment-216305579